# Is it possible to have both VS 2012 Express and VS 2012 Premium installed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I need both Visual Studio 2012 Express and Visual Studio 2012 Premium installed because of licensing reasons (I downloaded Visual Studio 2012 Premium from DreamSpark).

Is it possible to have them both installed on the same machine? Won't their installations clash with each other?

Comment: Couldn't you just try it and see what happens? Also, why do you need express installed when premium does all that express does and more?

Comment: Can't use software from DreamSpark for commercial use.

Comment: In that case, why have Premium installed?

Comment: Also, depending on what your commercial use is, you might be eligible for BizSpark.

Comment: I'm trying to learn (well in fact just check something) about WDK. And VS Express doesn't support WDK.

Comment: For any legal purpose, the restriction of the use of dreamspark is not enforceable.  Sometimes, what MS says and what is the law are different thing.

Comment: I know side-by-side (sxs) installation was previously supported for the same versions of different editions of the SKU's, and that sxs for the same edition with previous versions is currently supported, but not sure about current versions of different editions of the SKUs.  One possibly safe way to deal with this situation is to use a virtual machine.

Comment: Not to be an ass, because it's totally a legitimate question -- but can we offtopic this question back to programmers.stackexchange where it started? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Visual Studio Express for Web 2012 and Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 installed on the same machine, with no problems that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible like Alyce sad (+1). I know some colleagues which have 3 and more VS installed. I personally installed two generation (2008 and 2012). In some case installation sequence matters. There are also several Microsoft help-sites about this theme like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609%28VS.110%29.aspx).

Comment: The one time I did have problems with multiple installations, from memory, was with Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 and the Office 2013 Preview - the order I installed them in was wrong, and completely trashed my computer. Trying to uninstall them just made it worse. Not a fun week...